# Show results of joined tables even if some values don't match

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, database-relations

Access Database

```
table contacts
--------------
id
surname
name


table relations
---------------
contact_id
relation_id
```

Both contact_id and relation_id are foreign keys referenced to table contacts' id

I want to execute a query to get both the contact's surname/name and the relation's surname/name **if a relation for the current contact exist**. If it doesn't exist I want to get the contact's surname/name and blank values for the relation's fields.

**All this in one query**

EDIT:

I used left join. I am running the query using VB.NET:

```
Dim myOleDbDataReader As OleDbDataReader = _
    New OleDbCommand( _
    "SELECT c.id           AS contact_id " & _
    "     , c.surname      AS contact_surname " & _
    "     , c.name         AS contact_name " & _
    "     , c2.id          AS related_id " & _
    "     , c2.surname     AS related_surname " & _
    "     , c2.name        AS related_name " & _
    "FROM ((contacts c " & _
    "LEFT JOIN relations r " & _
    "ON c.id = r.contact_id) " & _
    "INNER JOIN contacts c2 " & _
    "ON c2.id = r.relation_id)" _
    , connection).ExecuteReader()
```

I get **OleDbException: Join expression not supported.**

They say in another post that:
"Access won't let you use conventional joins in the where clause when you use LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOINS in the FROM clause. It is probably intentional to get you to buy more expensive software." - ( [Is the join expression not supported by MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650490/is-the-join-expression-not-supported-by-ms-access) )

It is not exactly that. From some examples I tried I came to the conclusion that:

**Access won't let you use outer joins (LEFT/RIGHT) together with one or more INNER JOINS**.
What in John Carmack's name can I do?
I would like to avoid seperate select queries.
Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id       AS contact_id
     , c.surname  AS contact_surname
     , c.name     AS contact_name
     , c2.id      AS related_id
     , c2.surname AS related_surname
     , c2.name    AS related_name
FROM contacts c
  LEFT JOIN relations r
    ON c.id = r.contact_id
  JOIN contacts c2
    ON r.relation_id = c2.id
```

The above does **NOT work** in MS-Access.

This is slightly different (two left joins) but it **works**:

```
SELECT c.id       AS contact_id
     , c.surname  AS contact_surname
     , c.name     AS contact_name
     , c2.id      AS related_id
     , c2.surname AS related_surname
     , c2.name    AS related_name
FROM contacts c
  LEFT JOIN
    ( relations r
      LEFT  JOIN contacts AS c2
        ON r.relation_id = c2.id
    )  
    ON c.id = r.contact_id
```

Despite the second `LEFT JOIN`, it will give same result set, since the second LEFT JOIN involves a Foreign Key relationship (in the direction from many -> one).

To have a LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN you could use:

```
SELECT c.id       AS contact_id
     , c.surname  AS contact_surname
     , c.name     AS contact_name
     , g.id       AS related_id
     , g.surname  AS related_surname
     , g.name     AS related_name
FROM contacts c
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT r.contact_id
           , c2.id      
           , c2.surname
           , c2.name 
      FROM relations r
        INNER JOIN contacts AS c2
          ON r.relation_id = c2.id
    )  AS g
    ON c.id = g.contact_id
```

Comment: Should give syntax error in MS Access. Inner joins must before left joins and nested joins need parenthesises.

Comment: yes, i checked too. (long time I hadn't used Access). I'll edit in a few minutes.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Two left joins give the same result after all.